# Get PROCESS_INFORMATION from CreateProcess

Tags: c, windows, x86, inline-assembly, detours

Im trying to get the PROCESS_INFORMATION from CreateProcessW from exe.
what im doing is hooking the call by placing a jmp at the location an nopping bytes 
it jmps to my function
then I recall CreateProcessW the same way its done in the exe
then im trying to catch/log the data
then I jmp back to continue the stuff in exe

My problem is that its not logging the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` right
the `ProcessId` is not the same as the `PID` of the created process

This is the function im hooking
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFZRn.png

Then I place the hook/jmp

```
DWORD CreateProcessMidHookAddress = (DWORD)GetModuleHandleA("MyDll.dll") + 0x16F46;
DWORD CreateProcessMidHookRet = (DWORD)GetModuleHandleA("MyDll.dll") + 0x16F56;

placeJMP((BYTE*)CreateProcessMidHookAddress, (DWORD)CreateProcessMidHook, 16); // JMP from loader.dll + 0x16F46 to my function
```

An then here is my function
It gets called an the process is created
just the ProcessId is not the same processId as the created process

```
__declspec(naked) void CreateProcessMidHook()
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInformation;
    __asm
    {
        PUSH EDX; // 52
        PUSH EBP; // 55
        PUSH 0; // 6A 00
        PUSH 5; // 6A 05
        PUSH 0; // 6A 00
        PUSH 0; // 6A 00
        PUSH 0; // 6A 00
        PUSH ECX; // 51
        PUSH ESI; // 56
        CALL EAX; // FF D0  CALLS CreateProcessW

        // think problem is here
        MOV ProcessInformation, EDX;

        PUSHAD;
        PUSHFD;

    }

    // Log function is just like printf, logs to text file
    Log("ProcessId : 0x%X \n", ProcessInformation.dwProcessId);

    __asm
    {
        POPFD;
        POPAD;

        JMP[CreateProcessMidHookRet];
    }
}
```

Comment: `CreateProcessW` takes a pointer to `PROCESS_INFORMATION`. You need to find this pointer (it's the 10th parameter of CreateProcessW, so should be at [esp] when your hook gets control) and then to dereference it.

Comment: i was looking at it in ollybdg an think i found it at `[ESP + 0x1C]`
but i dont know how to copy that to my `PROCESS_INFOMATION` object
`MOV ProcessInformation, [ESP + 0x1C];` didnt work

Comment: I don't see how CreateProcessW can find its 10th parameter at [esp+0x1c]. Anyway, it's a POINTER. So you have to define `PROCESS_INFORMATION* ppi;` and then `mov ppi, [esp+0xWhatever]`, and then log ppi->dwProcessId.

Comment: you cant use `mov ppi, [esp+0x1C]`
gets error
error C2415: improper operand type

Comment: Yes, sorry, you cannot `mov` memory to memory. You need to do it in two 'mov's using a register. And I have a strong suspicion that there is something wrong with the stack and the 10th parameter: you have a local variable in the hook function, and if it's allocated on stack, it will prevent the actual 'ProcessInformation' (provided by a caller) from being passed to `CreateProcessW`, won't it?

Comment: Yeah im not sure how to fix this

`DWORD dwESP;` 
`mov dwESP, esp;` 
`ppi = (PROCESS_INFORMATION*)dwESP + 0x1C;`

did you mean something like that?

Comment: No. That won't work. What you probably need is: 1) define `ppi` (compiler will add some data on stack thus hiding the 10th parameter); 2) `push [esp+X]` to restore 10th parameter on top of stack; 3) all `push`es, `call` etc.; 4) `mov edx, [esp+X+4*9]`, `mov ppi, edx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working this out

What i did was i found where in `ESP` the data was stored

I then made a class to hold the data i needed an placed a void to jmp to the location i needed
`BYTE   void[0xAddress];`

Then i moved the data into my class
`MOV pClass, ESP;`

There are other ways of doing this
But this is what i could work out an get to work

Thanks heaps for your help